# Having trouble copying a remote database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL Workbench, and I'm having trouble copying a remote database into my local drive.

I don't have trouble connecting to either my local or the remote, but when I try to copy the database from remote, I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/db_copy_progress.py", line 155, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/db_copy_progress.py", line 641, in _row_count
    total = self._transferer.count_table_rows(self._working_set)
  File "/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/DataMigrator.py", line 285, in count_table_rows
    raise Exception("Error getting row count from source tables, wbcopytables exited with code %s" % out.returncode)
Exception: Error getting row count from source tables, wbcopytables exited with code 1
ERROR: Counting table rows to copy: Error getting row count from source tables, wbcopytables exited with code 1
Failed
```

Comment: What are your database versions?

Comment: The remote database I am trying to copy is 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 ((Ubuntu)) and my local is 8.0.17 (MySQL Community Server - GPL). It also says that the remote is not supported on workbench, could this be the problem?

Comment: try to import the dumb like eplained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump-upgrade-testing.html  first dthe definitions and routines. and then the data.